# how to connect to a printer and print a png image using python and PIL library in Ubuntu

Tags: python

how to connect to a printer and print a png image using python and PIL library in Ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
subprocess.call(['lp', 'foo.png'])
```

Comment: Well, sorry: this is neither Python, nor PIL. Of the three: it will work in Ubuntu. In the meantime I found out about `pkipplib` - still need to see if it works for me (could be cross-platform with network printers).